# Making sense of a definition - The Happy Number

Tags: graph-theory

Note, we are only using two colors in the definitions below (say red and blue).

A n-graph (complete, edge-colored, and has n vertices) is called *Happy* if there exists a vertex coloring such that each edge touches at least one vertex of the same color. We call such a vertex coloring *valid*.

We denote the minimum graph size that is forced to contain a Happy n-graph as $H(n)$. This is called the *Happy number*.

---

I am confused on the definition of a Happy number. What is meant by "*forced to contain*"? It seems to me that they want a small enough $m$-graph that ALWAYS contains a happy $n$-graph, but when will that be?

Let's consider $n=4$. So, what is $H(4)$? I say $H(4) \neq 4$  because of the below image [image: Forbidden 4-graph] Okay, does $H(4)= 5$? It CAN contain a happy 4-graph, but it does not always contain a happy 4-graph. Namely, because of the "Forbidden" $5$-graph: [image: Forbidden 5-graph] I'm pretty sure every $n>3$ $n$-graph has a particular edge coloring which causes the graph to not be happy.

So this brings my major question: **Because there exists an $m$-graph which is not Happy, for any $m>3$, how can we ever say that a graph of size $m$ is FORCED to contain a Happy $n$-graph?**

How can we have a $m$-graph be guaranteed to have an $n$-happy subgraph?

Comment: The $5$-graph you show may not itself be happy, but if it *contains* a happy subgraph with $4$ vertices, then $H(4)=5$ is still possible.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Is that the same as **forcing** a $m$-graph to contain a Happy $n$-graph? By your reasoning, couldn't we say that $H(n)=n+1$?

Comment: Well, really, by that reasoning we could always say $H(n)=n$ since every $n-graph$ can contain a happy $n$-graph

Comment: @Ozera From what I understand, $H(n)=k$ iff $k$ is the minimum natural number such that for any edge-coloring of clique $K_k$ there exists an edge-colored subclique $K_n$ (with the coloring taken from $K_k$) that is Happy.

Comment: $H(4)\le18$ because any edge-coloring of $K_{18}$ with two colors contains a **monochromatic** $K_4$, (see [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) and [Ramsey numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html)), i.e., with all edges having the same color; and of course monochramatic $\implies$ happy.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, $H(n)$ is the minimum sized complete graph guaranteed to contain a $n$-happy subgraph. This means that $H(n)=m$ is the $m$-graph which is the smallest graph that can contain a $n$-happy graph. See @dtldarek's and mjq's comments for more information on what I was confused on.